# What makes a brew bucket food grade?

Tags: equipment, bucket

This question usually pops up in my head every time I step into Home Depot and see all the orange buckets around.

What makes a bucket food grade?

Comment: related: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/11015/3914

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the type of plastic, and how it's manufactured (it has to do with the chemical properties of the plastic).   A food grade container will not allow most foods to leach toxic chemicals from it under normal operating conditions.

[Using Plastic Buckets in Food Storage](https://www.usaemergencysupply.com/information_center/packing_your_own_food_storage/plastic_food_storagebuckets.htm)

Comment: broken link. is this the correct one? https://www.usaemergencysupply.com/information-center/packing-your-own-food-storage/using-food-storage-buckets-and-containers

Answer (score 2):

Look for the recyclable marks on the buckets, usually on the bottom.  There should be three arrows in the shape of a triangle with a number in the center.  If the number is #1 or #2 then it is food grade.
Usually #2 which is HDPE or high density polyethylene.

Comment: It would appear that 1,2,4 and 5 are food grade according to: http://www.wikihow.com/Identify-Food-Grade-Buckets . Personally I usually looks for the Glass and Fork symbol.